# PowerBI Visual Tools (pbiviz) - Installation Error

Tags: node.js, powerbi, npm-install, pbiviz

I am trying to follow the given steps in https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-docs/blob/master/tools/README.md# installation to create my custom visuals in PowerBI.

I installed nodeJS 4.0+ and trying to install powerbi-visual-tools with the command `npm install -g powerbi-visuals-tools`. To confirm it was installed correctly we can run the command `pbviz` without any parameters which should display the help screen. But i am getting an error in my cmd

```
C:\>pbiviz
C:\Users\code1234\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\powerbi-visuals-tools\bin\pbiviz.js:30
let exec = require('child_process').execSync;
^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3

C:\>
```

Can any one help me in moving to the next steps in the PowerBI Visual Tools (pbiviz) - Installation

Comment: Please run `node -v` and tell me what it outputs. thanks.

Comment: @Lenny :`node -v` gives me output  `v0.12.2`

Comment: Then you need to upgrade node to 4.0+ The installer on their website should upgrade it.